# Why "may be rounded" from int to float, but "can be preserved" from int to double?

Tags: floating-point, rounding, integer-arithmetic

Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective says:

> When casting values between int, float, and double formats, the
> program changes the numeric values and the bit representations as
> follows (assuming data type int is 32 bits):
>
> - From int to float, the number cannot overﬂow, but it **may be rounded**.
> - From int or float to double, the exact numeric value **can be preserved** because double has both greater range (i.e., the range of
>   representable values), as well as greater precision (i.e., the number
>   of signiﬁcant bits).

Why "may be rounded" from int to float, but "can be preserved" from int to double?

Should it be the same in the both cases? (I guess both have no rounding?)

Answer (score 2):

> Should it be the same in the both cases?

No.  Typical `float` can *exactly* represent *all* integer values only up to about 2<sup>24</sup> while `double` can do so up to 2<sup>53</sup>.

Typical `int` is 32-bit and so some `int` values in the 2<sup>24</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup> range do not convert to `float` without rounding.

---

To extend the idea, large `long long` values may round when converted to `float` or `double`.

---

Another way to look at it for 32-bit `int` and 32-bit `float`.  Each can represent *about* 2<sup>32</sup> different values.  As `float` can represent many values with a fractionally part, there must be `int` values not representable exactly as `float`.  [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)